# Ranking functions representing running times from smallest to largest

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algorithms, asymptotics

rank the following functions representing running times from smallest to largest (in terms of growth rate with respect to n).

$2n^3+12n^2+5$

$8(log n)^2$

$1.5n$

$n^4-12n^3$

$4n^3logn$

$4n^3$

$n!$

$7n+6$

I am not looking for an exact answer to this question. Just a few approaches to help me get started will be fine. Haven't been able to grasp this concept very well so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From best to worst, here is $O(f(n))$ ranked for some common functions. Most of your functions appear to fit in one of these categories. Let $x>1$ be a constant.
$$O(n!)>O(x^n)>O(n^x)>O(n\log(n))>O(n)>O(\log(n))>O(x)$$
The leading term of a polynomial determines its growth. I expect you'll find $8(\log(n))^2$ trickier than the rest but I think you'll be able to determine its placement based on the above ordering. If you want to compare functions visually, try graphing them together and seeing how they compare as $n$ gets large.

In general, you can compare two functions' rate of growth by computing
$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{f(n)}{g(n)}$$
If $L=\infty$ then $f$ grows faster than $g$, if $L=0$ then $g$ grows faster than $f$. Otherwise, the functions grow at the same rate.